# How would I remove texture from these areas

Tags: texturing, uv

[image: highlighted parts are the parts i dont want to have the brick texture. like the roof.]

I am new to blender so I dont know how to remove specific parts of textures. I have the uv editor open but dont see a way to delete the selected faces.

Answer (score 4):

you could either use a second material and select the faces, select the second material and hit "assign"

or in uv editor, you can select this:

[image]

to sync and then select the faces on your objects, and in UV editing hit S 0 and then G and move that point outside the uv grid.

[image]

third solution (thanks to moonboots):  use a mask in a Mix Shader or Mix Color in order to separate this part

Comment: third solution is to use a mask in a Mix Shader or Mix Color in order to separate this part

Comment: thx! added this to my answer